# Newbie problems with printing strings and variables in Python

Tags: python, variables, printing

I am completely new to coding and having just got hold of a Raspberry Pi i am starting out from scratch. Im trying a simple program to display a multiplication table chosen from an input off the user. the entire code is listed below - sorry if its scruffy

The output I'm looking for is for example

```
1 x 5 = 5
2 x 5 = 10
3 x 5 = 15
```

etc...

What I actually get is:

```
(((1, "x"), 5), ' + ') 5)
(((2, "x"), 5), ' + ') 10)
(((3, "x"), 5), ' + ') 15)
```

etc...

Can anyone help me with a reason as to why this is coming out this way? I appreciate the code may be a little scruffy and bloated. I am trying to use a couple of different methods to set the variables etc just for the sake of experimentation.

thank you in advance
Mike

```
m = int(1)
z = input ("What table would you like to see?")
t = int(z)
while m <13:
    e = int(m*t)
    sumA = (m, " x ")
    sumB = (sumA, t)
    sumC = (sumB, " + ")
    print (sumC, e)
    m += 1
```

Comment: Is this Python 2 or 3? I *suspect* Python 3, but you seem to have a stray extra `)` in your actual output; I'd expect your code to print `(((1, "x"), 5), ' + ') 5`, *not* `(((1, "x"), 5), ' + ') 5)`.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use tuples as your intermediary variables; just print the whole thing:

```
while m <13:
    e = m * t
    print(m, 'x', t, '+', e)
    m += 1
```

and you may want to use a `range()`-based loop instead of `while`:

```
z = input ("What table would you like to see?")
t = int(z)
for m in range(1, 13):
    e = m * t
    print(m, 'x', t, '+', e)
```

Note that there is no need to call `int()` so many times; use it *only* on the return value of `input()`, which is a string otherwise.

Comment: Great stuff thanks. That second print statement did exactly what I need. I did try something along those lines previously but I didnt quite get the punctuation right. Didnt realise I had created tuples - no idea what they are! Maybe thats in the next lesson I will try.

Answer (score 2):

1. you don't need to specify the type in python. instead of `m = int(1)`, you could just say `m= 1`, and `e = m* t`
2. you are building tuples instead of formatting the output, if you want to format the pirntout, the simplest way here is to use `format` as discussed from python doc: http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html. The code would be like,

   ```
   print("{0} x {1} = {2}".format(m, t, e))
   ```